# How to share my localserver with another computer?

Tags: ubuntu, ip, localhost, localserver

I am trying to see my localhost in another computer(which is in the same network) but it doesn't seem to work. 
I have found my static IP address and use it to see the localserver but I get nothing back.

```
       http://xxx.xxx.x.x/project/test.php
```

I am working on an UBUNTU system and running localserver through LAMP.

Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is the other computer in the same network?

Comment: You mean in the same WLAN? Yes it is.

Comment: Then check out the port...I don't really know what else it could be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all make sure your on the same network, and if not you need to set up port forwarding in your router so that other people can acces your computer with the public IP of your router.

If your computer has a firewall that blocks on port 80 you won't be able to have any incoming connections (i.e. other computers can't access your site). So you would need to open your firewall for `http` connections on port `80`.

Comment: Thanks. The computers are in the same network (wlan). Would it work if I deactivate the firewall? I have to do this in both computers?

Comment: You will only need to disable the firewall on the server-computer. But you don't need to do this for all ports, only port 80.

Comment: I get a very strange behavior. Although in the beginning it worked now for some reason it doesn't. I pinged the ip of the other computer and its unreachable. Some times it works and some times it doesnt work.